# Skip email confirmation when creating a new user using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise, seed, devise-confirmable

I have a user registration page and will send the information to couple of admin users that one new user registered in the site.

Now, I created the seed data with list of users (200+). So, It'll send the 200+ email to the respective admin users. Hence, I want to stop send the mail confirmation to admin users when creating new user.

Comment: Are you using a gem for authentication? If so, which one?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Devise gem for authentication.

Answer (score 14):

For Devise, add `user.skip_confirmation!` before saving.

```
user = User.new(
    :email => 'person@example.com',
    :password => 'password1',
    :password_confirmation => 'password1'
  )
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save!
```

Cite: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2296

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to do something like

```
user = User.new.tap do |u|
  u.email = 'email@server.com'
  u.password = 'hackme!'
  u.password_confirmation = 'hackme!'
  u.skip_confirmation!
  u.save!
end
```

In that way, you instantiate the object, skip the confirmation and save it in one step and return it to the user variable.

It's just another way to do the same in one step.