# SocketError: getaddrinfo while running heroku run rake db:seed on a Heroku App-Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using `Rails4 and ruby2.0.0`. I pushed my app on `Heroku` & I m getting this error when I run heroku run rake db:seed

Running `rake db:seed` attached to terminal... up, `run.6298`

> Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.8ms)
>
> Sent mail to xyz@gmail.com (29.3ms) rake aborted! SocketError:
>   getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in`
>   do_delivery'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in
>   `block in deliver'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:456:in`
>   block in deliver_mail'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in
>   `block in instrument'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`
>   instrument'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in
>   `instrument'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:454:in`
>   deliver_mail'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in
>   `deliver'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:173:in`
>   send_devise_notification'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:102:in
>   `send_confirmation_instructions'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:158:in`
>   send_on_create_confirmation_instructions'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in
>   `_run__3822695918417406283__create__callbacks'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in`
>   run_callbacks'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in
>   `create_record'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in`
>   create_record'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:477:in
>   `create_or_update'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in`
>   block in create_or_update'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:383:in
>   `_run__3822695918417406283__save__callbacks'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in`
>   run_callbacks'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in
>   `create_or_update'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:106:in`
>   save'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in
>   `save'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in`
>   save'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in save'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in`block in with_transaction_returning_status'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in
>   `block in transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in`
>   within_new_transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in
>   `transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in`transaction'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in`block in save'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:281:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in`save' /app/db/seeds.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in`load'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in`load_dependency'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:540:in`
>   load_seed'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:154:in
>   `load_seed'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:181:in`
>   block (2 levels) in ' Tasks: TOP => db:seed (See full
>   trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating devise users in your seed file. Devise automatically sends some emails E.g. email_confirmation.

So you have to set up a proper ActionMailer for production Environment. You might be using an another heroku service for that. E.g [mailgun](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mailgun)

You can also [bypass devise email_confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798573/skip-email-confirmation-when-creating-a-new-user-using-devise) in your seed file.

Comment: Thank you, earlier I tried skipping email_confirmation in heroku console, but then the user was not getting saved. If you know why heroku console was not saving the user then please tell me. Doing same in seed file worked.